# React HighCharts - Is 3D available for Column chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, highcharts, axis

In react app I am using `highcharts` for graphical representation of data.
I want 3D Column chart with 3 axis like `X, Y, Z`.

I have tried one example by referring `scatter3d` chart.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import highcharts3d from "highcharts/highcharts-3d";
import highcharts3dModule from "highcharts/modules/exporting";

highcharts3d(Highcharts);
highcharts3dModule(Highcharts);

const ThreeDHistogram = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      chart: {
        type: "scatter3d",
        options3d: {
          enabled: true,
          alpha: 20,
          beta: 30,
          depth: 400,
          viewDistance: 10,
          frame: {
            bottom: {
              size: 1,
              color: "rgba(0,0,0,0.05)",
            },
          },
        },
      },
      title: {
        text: "",
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: "",
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 80,
        title: {
          text: "Y Axis",
        },
      },
      xAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 80,
        title: {
          text: "X Axis",
        },
        gridLineWidth: 1,
      },
      zAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200,
        title: {
          text: "Z Axis",
        },
        showFirstLabel: false,
      },
      series: [
        {
          data: [
            { x: 0, y: 41, z: 21, color: "#5ac8fa" },
            { x: 11, y: 51, z: 42, color: "#5ac8fa" },
            { x: 11, y: 31, z: 65, color: "#5ac8fa" },
            { x: 22, y: 63, z: 28, color: "#5ac8fa" },
            { x: 22, y: 67, z: 45, color: "#5ac8fa" },
            { x: 44, y: 58, z: 74, color: "#5ac8fa" },
            { x: 44, y: 52, z: 84, color: "#5ac8fa" },
            { x: 77, y: 19, z: 33, color: "#5ac8fa" },
            { x: 77, y: 81, z: 52, color: "#5ac8fa" },
            { x: 88, y: 91, z: 85, color: "#5ac8fa" },
            { x: 60, y: 55, z: 155, color: "#5ac8fa" },
            { x: 32, y: 55, z: 105, color: "#5ac8fa" },
            { x: 10, y: 66, z: 185, color: "#aabdff" },
            { x: 70, y: 66, z: 15, color: "#5ac8fa" },
            { x: 72, y: 86, z: 150, color: "#aabdff" },
          ],
          name: "",
        },
      ],
    };

    Highcharts.chart("highcharts-container", options);
  }, []);

  return <div id="highcharts-container" />;
};

export default ThreeDHistogram;
```

Here, values are not plotting on `Z` axis, only it is on X and Y axis. How can I make it available for all axis? And I want 3D Column chart itself.

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts doesn't support z coordinates for column series in 3d mode. It should be implemented like it's done in scatter3d series: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.scatter3d.data.z.

You can submit a feature request on our GH: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts

There is also a way to draw columns on different z-positions using stacks, but it's more like a workaround than a solution:

**Demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-64tgdy